# How to get the list of friend_request using facebook API

Tags: facebook

How to get the list of friend_request using facebook API.
For example, user A,has logged in.
Use B send request of adding friends to A
Now, I want to get the friend_request of user A, how to do?
May the facebook graph API could not support the operate, yes or not?

At the same time, I would like to use FQL as below,
SELECT uid_from FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to=204686
（http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request）
But, how to send the FQL to facebook server?which url?
like this:https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select .... &access_token=....format=json...  yes or not?
any other idea?
Thank you!

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java then why not use one of available [Java Facebook APIs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Java)? Let API worry about which request to send where. Currently I am using [RestFB API](http://restfb.com/), there are plenty of examples on their site including how to execute FQL.

**UPDATE**

Ok, if you have to send requests manually then sending them using URL you provided is correct. Just remember that you would need to encode your FQL query before sending it as a param (`URLEncoder` in java would do the trick). You can play with the queries on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query) and it will show you how your request should look like and what is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the program was run on android platform. I'm not sure that RestFB API whether could run on android.
I will study the source code of RestFB API. Maybe some useful idea found.
Thank you all the same.

Comment: Thank you.
SELECT uid,status_id,message,time FROM status WHERE uid =100001363869440 limit 1
I have queried the FQL as above, on this page(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query), I could get the result smooth,but in my programme on android platform, it returned empty set when I used the same FQL.

Comment: @Simon Sorry I am not familiar with Android. Maybe just create another question and someone would be able to help.

Comment: Thank you all the same! The issue has been closed right now! The problem is wrong permission!~~~~:)Thank you!